# Problems writing a query to join two tables

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm working on a script which purpose is to grant site users access to different sections of the site menu. For this I have created two tables, "menu" and "rights":

```
menu
- id
- section_name

rights
- id
- menu_id (references column id from menu table)
- user_id (references column id from users table)
```

How can a query be written in order to get all menu sections and mark the ones where a given user has access.

I'm using PHP and Postgres.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT M.*, CASE WHEN R.user_id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS access FROM menu AS M
LEFT JOIN rights AS R ON (R.menu_id = M.id AND R.user_id = 1)
```

Comment: @arex1337: well it's not ok because I want to get all the sections from the menu, not only the ones where the user has access, and for the ones where user has access show a new column with a value (something like '1')

Comment: I get this error: "function if(boolean, integer, integer) does not exist" and this hint: "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: Sorry, I'm a MySQL user and new to postgresql. Try my updated code :)

Comment: No error this time, but still the same output (just the sections where user has access). It's true that the "access" column is also available now. I feel you're getting close :)